# Marking functions with comment-like tags for their user

Tags: c++, macros

How would I go about telling the user of a function that he/she should be calling the function within a specific context or in a specific way? Say for example, mark a function must only be called on a designated thread.

Basically, something that doesn't affect the behavior of the program but conveys information not using comments nor changing function names and in a uniform, non-code-repeating way(using macros?) across all functions that are marked. My first thought is using an empty macro in the function definition, this works but the problem is that tools like intellisense don't display this "tag" of sorts to the user.

Comment: A lot of IDEs will do this for you if you put some comments before the function definition. Then when you come to call the function, the notes appear in a tooltip.

Comment: Maybe one of the [attributes](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/attributes) will help.

Comment: What's wrong with comments? Intellisense will display them.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat those incur repetition and run the risk of not being uniform.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat if only there were a way to use macros that evaluate to comments....

Comment: How about doing an `assert()`at the beginning of the function?

Comment: I recommend using Doxygen.  This will help define the interface for a function.

Comment: Having your function control when it is called is difficult, although there may be some ways like using counters or using the clock, but other conditions are more difficult.